# Failed to create a control from assembly 'SharePointBoost.License...'

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

One of my custom SharePoint 2010 application on the server throwing following error,

> Failed to create a control from assembly 'SharePointBoost.License,
>   Version=2.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=15fd9ef9a2ec3a95',
>   class 'SharePointBoost.License.Management.RedirectControl': The
>   control with assembly name 'SharePointBoost.License, Version=2.0.8.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=15fd9ef9a2ec3a95' class name
>   'SharePointBoost.License.Management.RedirectControl' is not allowed
>   for web at URL 'xxxxxxxx'. The type is not registered as safe.

Everything was working fine but suddenly it's happening from past few days and strangely no new code or changes is deployed in between.

Any clues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should ask the vendor for help :-

Failed to create a control from assembly '**SharePointBoost.License**, Version=2.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=15fd9ef9a2ec3a95', class '**SharePointBoost.License.Management.RedirectControl**':

http://www.boostsolutions.com/support.html